# How to grep only show path/filename?

Tags: linux, grep

I'm trying to locate the files which contain certain pattern, so I use `grep -ir 'pattern' .` to search all files under current directory. But I don't want to see the content of each file, I only need the path/filename. How can I do that?

Ps: Because some JSON file contains very long text in one line, then it will occupy the whole screen. I don't want to filter out those JSON files, because that's what I'm trying to locate

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`grep -l` will output JUST the names of files which matched, without showing the actual match.

Comment: Yeah, and I actually want to know how many matches in each particular file.

Comment: why not sudo grep -i -r "text to search" /dir

Comment: ahhhh - check this post, http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65181/list-the-files-containing-a-particular-word-in-their-text

Comment: there's `grep -c` for that. but you'd have to test that with -l, since -l is a posix spec and terminates the search in any file upon the first match.

Comment: @MarcB I tried, you don't need -l. grep -c will only show the path with count number.